Too many queueable jobs added to the queue with unremovable queue
Im in desperate mode. The situation is following:
there are three objects,

Account,
Publisher(child of account, master-detail),
app(child of publisher, master-detail).

Creating/updating app in a way I need to do it, triggers account trigger that launches a queueable from managed package. Whenever I try to insert those apps, I always get:
 Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2 

because of that account managed package trigger.

Process was working in a way that apps were queried(using callout) and inserted within same transaction,

I thought that was a problem so I changed it that now all apps sit in new custom object custom field as JSON string. i was able to retrieve way more apps, but when I tried to insert them all in a batch(200 chunk size) 99% of chunks errored out with too many queueable jobs.


Please somebody help me with what kind of approach can be used here to synchronously upsert all these 150k apps with a delay for a time for account trigger to process.
I was thinking of scheduling new batch and cancelling existing but I need help with implementation on how to do this. Or using queueable class with counter and built-in salesforce delay feature so after one queueable finished, new one will be launched in couple minutes.

Hi @NickC, answers are not helpful because account trigger is a black box as it is from managed package. Also my batch size was never >200 so the answer is not relevant for my approach. i tried running in with batch size 200, 50 and now 10 and results are better with lower batch sizes but I cant set it as 1 because there are 130k apps

Have you contacted the managed package vendor to see if they have any workarounds?

its a private app exchange app and they made a rebrading or were acquired by another company, I'm not sure that this new company is even aware of that package to be honest because they didn't change the branding but yeah, contacted them today after trying different approaches to make a workaround myself @DavidCheng
